# AVAssetWriter – Writing an AIFF – Always Rejects the input

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, core-audio, avassetwriter

Anyone made an AVAssetWriter that successfully writes an AIFF file ? It keeps rejecting the AVAssetWriterInput I am trying to add with these settings:

```
writerInput audio settings: {
    AVChannelLayoutKey = {empty AudioChannelLayout with kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo};
    AVFormatIDKey = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey = 32;
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey = 0;
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey = 0;
    AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved = 0;
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey = 2;
    AVSampleRateKey = 48000;
}
```

For whatever reason I can use the same settings with a AVFileTypeWAVE file instead of AVFileTypeAIFF and it'll work fine.

Comment: Typically AIFF is big-endian although I don't know if that is the issue.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. ‍♂️ I twiddled other settings (float vs int etc) but not that one.

Comment: Additional note for posterity: 32-bit float is also not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIFF is usually big-endian. Try setting `AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey` to `1`.